# Como obter o MD5 de um arquivo em Delphi?

Tags: delphi, md5

Como obter o [MD5](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) de um arquivo em Delphi?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O código abaixo usa o Indy, que acompanha o Delphi.

```pascal
uses
  IdHashMessageDigest, IdHash;

function MD5DoArquivo(const FileName: string): string;
var
  IdMD5: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  IdMD5 := nil;
  FS := nil;
  try
    IdMD5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
    FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    Result := IdMD5.HashStreamAsHex(FS)
  finally
    FS.Free;
    IdMD5.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 por usar um componente praticamente nativo.

Answer (score 4):

Nas versões mais antigas do [`Delphi`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi)(como a 7), o componente [`Indy`](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx) não é embutido por padrão. Caso você queira fazer isso sem o uso de componentes, você pode utilizar [**`esse código`**](http://svn.softwarepublico.gov.br/trac/cacic/browser/cacic/trunk/agente-windows/md5.pas?rev=732) *redistribuído* pelos desenvolvedores do software `CACIC`.

Por exemplo, para calcular a MD5 de uma string, utiliza-se:

```
Uses md5;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage(MD5Print(MD5String('FoooBarrr')));
end;
```

Para calcular a *MD5* de um arquivo, utiliza-se:

```
Uses md5;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage(MD5Print(MD5File('Arquivo.exe')));
end;
```

:-)